# Propositional Logic help

Tags: proof-writing

Trying to get a transformational proof for "$(-p\vee q) \wedge (-q\vee p)$" to "$(p\vee q) \to (p\wedge q)$", any idea on the next step I can take?

I'm not looking for an answer just a hint.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: $A$ → $B$ is equivalent to $\neg A \vee B$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Start with the Distribution rule for **and** over **or**.